# Javascript onmouseover/onmouseout Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having The following issue, this code:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <div id="over-1" class="glass" onmouseout="$(this).stop().fadeOut();"></div>
    <img src="img.jpg" onmouseover="$('#over-1').stop().fadeIn();" />
</div>
```

The mouse over and mouse out works fine, however on occasion the overlay image fades back in by itself after fading out, I have searched for a solution, so far being told to use jquerys hover function etc and similar, however so far no solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle that shows what you're trying to achieve there? http://fiddle.jshell.net

Comment: why not use onmouseover and onmouseout on the same element? Use both of them with the <div>, or with the <img>.

Answer (score 0):

Set an additional fadeOut() call on the container "image-container" and it'll solve the issue

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".image-container", function(){
    $("#over-1").fadeOut();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSvFN/)